# How to query date differences between dates of same column?

Tags: oracle, date, difference

I have a table with a date field and I need a query to return the ID of records that are on a certain day.

Example

```
ID   UPDATED_DATE
42   31-DEC-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
43   24-DEC-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
44   03-DEC-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
45   18-NOV-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
46   08-NOV-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
47   01-NOV-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
48   26-OCT-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
49   04-OCT-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
50   20-SEP-19 12.00.00.000000000 AM
```

I need a query to find if the DAY part of the date is >= 1 and < 5.

In the example, I will get the ID as 44, 47 and 49 as output.

Can anyone help me for the query, please?

Comment: Difference = take two values and subtract one from the other. Do you really mean difference? If you do mean difference, then why is `45, 18-NOV` and `50, 20-SEP` not included (and various others) where the difference between the day-of-month is less than 5 days? If you don't mean difference then please don't use well-defined mathematical terms to mean something else.

Answer (score 0):

Use `TO_CHAR` with appropriate format mask:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> with test as
  2    (select 42 id, date '2019-12-31' updated_date from dual union all
  3     select 43, date '2019-12-24' from dual union all
  4     select 44, date '2019-12-03' from dual union all
  5     select 45, date '2019-11-18' from dual union all
  6     select 46, date '2019-11-08' from dual union all
  7     select 47, date '2019-11-01' from dual union all
  8     select 48, date '2019-10-26' from dual union all
  9     select 49, date '2019-10-04' from dual union all
 10     select 50, date '2019-09-20' from dual
 11    )
 12  select id, updated_date, to_char(updated_date, 'fmdd') dd
 13  from test
 14  where to_char(updated_date, 'fmdd') >= 1
 15    and to_char(updated_date, 'fmdd') <  5
 16  order by id;

        ID UPDATED_DA DD
---------- ---------- --
        44 03.12.2019 3
        47 01.11.2019 1
        49 04.10.2019 4

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference (as per the [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/833b50f4-3faa-41e5-92e8-ffc6e4dedfdb/view-source)) between day-of-month of two rows to be between 1 and 4 days then use `LAG`/`LEAD`:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       UPDATED_DATE
FROM   (
  SELECT ID,
         UPDATED_DATE,
         EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) AS day,
         LAG( EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) )
           OVER ( ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) ) AS prev_day,
         LEAD( EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) )
           OVER ( ORDER BY EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) ) AS next_day
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  day - prev_day BETWEEN 1 AND 4
OR     next_day - day BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

Which for your test data ouptuts:

> ```
> ID | UPDATED_DATE         
> -: | :--------------------
> 47 | 01-NOV-19 12:00:00 AM
> 44 | 03-DEC-19 12:00:00 AM
> 49 | 04-OCT-19 12:00:00 AM
> 46 | 08-NOV-19 12:00:00 AM
> 45 | 18-NOV-19 12:00:00 AM
> 50 | 20-SEP-19 12:00:00 AM
> 43 | 24-DEC-19 12:00:00 AM
> 48 | 26-OCT-19 12:00:00 AM
> ```

If you want the day-of-month to be between 1 and 4 then use `EXTRACT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  EXTRACT(DAY FROM updated_date) BETWEEN 1 AND 4
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> ID | UPDATED_DATE         
> -: | :--------------------
> 44 | 03-DEC-19 12:00:00 AM
> 47 | 01-NOV-19 12:00:00 AM
> 49 | 04-OCT-19 12:00:00 AM
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=088f0d41c93e2d3ade7c2e4ebf6db8a6)*